# Initialize right variable for while loop

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop

I wrote a program to count the number of integers that are positive, negative or zero until you enter q to stop the program. I was asking if this is the correct way to set up the while loop if you are using the character "q" to terminate the program?

```
int number = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int positive = 0;
    int negative = 0;
    int zero = 0;
    boolean validInput = true;


while(validInput == true){
    System.out.printf("Number (q to quit): ");
    if(input.hasNextInt()){
        number = input.nextInt();
        count++;
        total += number;
    }
    else if (number > 0){
        positive++;
    }
    else if (number < 0){
        negative++;
    }
    else if (number == 0){
        zero++;
    }
    if (validInput == false) {
        input.next();
    }
```

Comment: what issue do you have?

Comment: Looks like the only way out of the loop is when `validInput` is false but I don't see that happening anywhere, do you?

Comment: I don't know if I used the boolean variable correctly because the program is just continuous, even when I test it out & enter "q".

Comment: You never actually set `validInput = false` nor check whether Q has been typed...

Comment: where do you update validInput?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know how to check if Q has been typed or not.

Comment: @Skippy, you need to get a string input, not an integer input. Then check if the string is a number using parse int or if the string is 'q' then set validInput to false if it is.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was that you were not dealing with the user input properly, I fixed up the code and it now runs as described:

```
int number = 0;
int count = 0;
int total = 0;
int positive = 0;
int negative = 0;
int zero = 0;
boolean validInput = true;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Scans for user input, I assume you had this in your original code

while(validInput == true){
    System.out.printf("Number (q to quit): ");
    String enteredValue = input.nextLine();
    try { //test is value is an integer
        number = Integer.parseInt(enteredValue); 

        count++;
        total += number;
        if (number > 0){
            positive++;
        }
        else if (number < 0){
            negative++;
        }
        else if (number == 0){
            zero++;
        }
    } 
    catch(NumberFormatException e) { //if it is not an integer:
        validInput = !enteredValue.equals("q");
    }
}
```